# How to use Go -buildmode=archive

Tags: go

Using -buildmode=archive produces mylib.a. I'm not fully understanding the steps required to then use this library in another Go program.

I've tried instead generating -buildmode=c-archive which produces a header file and archive, but the headerfile is not designed to be imported using cgo (there is conflicts with imported types).
Research online has yielded the conclusion that -buildmode=c-archive is specifically not designed for cgo use for this reason.

My query is what is -buildmode=archive actually used for if it cannot be included?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not fully understanding the steps required to then use this library in another Go program.

It can be tricky. Need to look into each compiler toolchain for linking them correctly, i.e. gcc/clang etc. and find how, and if it's even possible to link them and use them.

> What is -buildmode=archive actually used for if it cannot be included?

From the docs: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go

> -buildmode=archive
>
> Build the listed non-main packages into .a files. Packages named
> main are ignored.

That's what it does, what you do with it, it's up to you, there's tons of information online, for example: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html